# How to convert Android's contacts2.db to .vcf?

Tags: android, database

I have extracted my contacts2.db from a nandroid backup. I'd like to convert that to one or many .vcf files so that I can use my contacts in other applications.

I already found [an answer that dealt with .db files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182591/how-can-i-open-db-files) but it did not work for this. I don't know if I did something wrong.

Comment: Do you want to export your contacts numbers or convert a `.db` file to `.vcf`? Because that is not the only way

Comment: What kind of file is your .db file, actually? Post the output of `file contacts2.db` run from a terminal in the directory where the file resides.

Comment: @tgies `contacts2.db` is a sqlite3 database.

Comment: @Lucio Now I have the nandroid backup, so I extracted the contacts2.db, and I want to convert it to a .vcf file, so i could have my contacts in my new phone (I didn't use the google sync, I forgot)

Comment: "ir did not work for this", how?

Comment: I have .vcf created but it has nothing in it ! so i have no result !

Comment: @Oli I assumed as much; I was mainly trying to guide the asker into a better understanding of how file types work and how to go about converting a file of unknown type.

Answer (score 10):

This seems to have been [answered on our Android sister-site](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/32783/13889) by [Chauncellor](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/23126/chauncellor):

> Well, this took a long time. For future searchers, here's what you can do:
>
> Find your contacts2.db file hidden somewhere in Android. Most of the time it's located in /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases. I was lucky and found it in a search through Titanium Backups' tarballs. Nab that file. It has everything in it in a sql database.
>
> I then found this excellent script to extract and convert all contacts into a .vcf format for easy importing into the next device. It's located [here](https://github.com/stachre/dump-contacts2db) on Github and requires two dependencies (on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine in which it was written for): sqllite3 and libsqllite3-dev:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
> ```
>
> After dependencies are satisfied, save the script on Github as dbconverter.sh. Mark it as executable:
>
> ```
> chmod +x dbconverter.sh
> ```
>
> use the script like this:
>
> ```
> ./dbconverter.sh contacts2.db > contacts2.vcf
> ```
>
> You will then have a lovely .vcf file for easy importing into your phone.

There are also other programmatic approaches on SO:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18955512/converting-db-to-vcf

Comment: ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ./dbconverter.sh contacts2.db > contacts2.vcf
bash: ./dbconverter.sh: No such file or directory ... I don't know what to do here!

Comment: You have to download and make executable the script from github.

Comment: I downloaded the script, from the button on the right "Download Zip" and i did make the file "dbconverter.sh" executable, Properties,Permission tab, Check “Allow executing file as program.”

Comment: Ancient answer and OP is probably not here to mark it as accepted, but if anyone else is looking for this  just wanted to report that it worked perfectly fine for me after 5 years, though I'm cheating because I'm a debian user. I just cloned the repo, marked it as executable, and successfully converted my file.